# Avoid Grails formatting

Tags: java, grails, integer, number-formatting

I'm having an issue with a Grails app.

On some occasions, when retrieving an instance with MyObject.get(id), I get this exception:

`Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String`

So I did this:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(params.id);

MyObject.get(i);
```

However, the a new problem appears. `Integer#valueOf(String)` seems to return a formatted value, so if `params.id` is greater than 1000, `i` gets a decimal point (e.g `1253` ->`1.253`).

## Update

After some more research, I've found that the value of `params.id` is coming with the decimal dot, even though it's not present in the query string:

`http://somesite.com//action?other=33&id=1485`

`params.id = 1.485`

Why is that decimal point there? Is there any "grailsy" approach to this?

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [Simple Type Converters section of the Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.12%20Simple%20Type%20Converters), you can convert incoming parameters from String to int like so:

```
def i = params.int('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

I often use groovy syntax to do this:

```
def i = (params.id as int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Integer.parseInt instead of Integer.valueOf

Answer (score 0):

I have noted that if I use this:

> ${fieldValue(bean:myBean,field:'aLongField')}

In a GSP page, it will be formatted and displayed like "1.485" or " 1,485" depending on the current locale.

If I use:

> ${myBean.aLongField }

or even

> ${myBean.aLongField.toString() }

Does not call NumberFormat and display the raw value.